# Makefile: print BUILD SUCCESSFUL or BUILD FAILED

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using Makefile for building my C++ project. It is a little bit annoying, that sometimes it is hard to find out if the build was successful or it was failed. I'd like to see a clear statement in the end of the build like in gradle.

If build passed:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

If build failed:

```
BUILD FAILED
```

For positive case I've found this solution:

```
all: dependencies #every job is done in dependencies
    echo "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think `c` and `c++` flags are off-topic for that question.

Comment: @kaylum According to the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors), make should stop processing the recipe if `do something` fails. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Actually I do everything in dependencies and the only target in this rule is the echo. I change the question accordingly.

Comment: @GregKikola Ah, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- A common principle of Unix (or any command-line, really) software is "if all is well, be quiet".  Of course Make itself (and makefiles written in the usual ways) already violate that rule left and right, but it's still a nice guideline...
- Unix command-line programs communicate success/fail using the exit status, so in terminal you can just do `echo $?` right after invoking Make.  `0` is success, anything else is not.
- Regardless of the aesthetic points above, getting Make to do something reliably in case of *failure* is hard, because it is not designed to do that.  It's vastly easier to wrap the Make invocation with a shell script, along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/sh

if make "$@"; then
  echo BUILD SUCCESSFUL
else
  echo BUILD FAILED
fi
```